# how to get value of a selected Item in drop down list?

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I need to select values from selected item in a drop down list in asp.net. in this code:

```
protected void EducationFeildsList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(EducationFeildsList.SelectedIndex);
    Label1.Text = index.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

But it seems that the value could not be read and so label1.text wasn't changed. how I could get the correct value of a selected item in this situation?

Comment: Does debugger step into this function?

Comment: It does not run when I try to debug my program.

Comment: I believe that's because DropDown does not cause PostBack by default. Set AutoPostBack = true

Comment: Thank you Uriil,You are right. My problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void EducationFeildsList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  If (!IsPostback)
   {
    Label1.Text = Dropdownlist1.Selectedvalue;
   }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that the Page_Load is executed before the SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: Hmm, i think that SelectedIndexChanged always will be on PostBack

Answer (score 0):

Set AutoPosback prperty of DDL to **TRUE**

Use the Parse

```
protected void EducationFeildsList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int index = int.Parse(EducationFeildsList.SelectedIndex);
Label1.Text = index.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```